When I tried updating to Node 20.14 from Node 14 and ran yarn test I started getting this error
Started getting this error when i ran yarn test in node 20.14 as i wanted to upgrade my node version from 14 to 20.14 
my package.json -
{

  "main": "server.js",

  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "5.8.4",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.2",
    "adm-zip": "^0.5.9",
    "axios": "0.21.4",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "bunyan": "1.8.15",
    "consul": "^0.40.0",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "couchbase": "4.2.5",
    "crypto-random-int": "1.0.1",
    "csv-stream": "^0.2.0",
    "csv-writer": "^1.6.0",
    "csvtojson": "2.0.10",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "elastic-apm-node": "4.7.1",
    "express": "4.17.3",
    "express-requests-logger": "4.0.0",
    "find-config": "1.0.0",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "firebase-admin": "9.4.2",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-html-reporters": "^3.1.4",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "json2csv": "5.0.6",
    "jwt-decode": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "kafkajs": "^1.15.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "memory-cache": "0.2.0",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "mongodb": "6.8.0",
    "multer": "1.4.2",
    "nodemon": "2.0.4",
    "objects-to-csv": "1.3.6",
    "serialize-error": "8.0.1",
    "through2": "^4.0.2",
    "unirest": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runInBand",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js",
    "start:local": "NODE_ENV=local nodemon server.js",
    "start:production": "node server.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3"
  }
}

I am using Mac M3 Chip and I tried upgrading the node version from 14 to 20.14 and tried to run yarn test but it threw this error - error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
With node 14 it works fine.
The dependencies i upgraded -
Couchbase - 3.1.3 to 4.2.5
elastic-apm-node - 3.9.0 to 4.7.1
mongodb - 3.6.4 to 6.8.0
Please click on the title to see the attached image . Please help!

SIGSEGV (signal segmentation violation) is an error signal in Unix systems (Linux). The error appears when a program or code tries to access an invalid memory location - hope that helps

@JaromandaX When i switch back to node 14 the test command and the test cases work fine but it fails with node 20. Is there a way to know where exactly this is happening as even after using --verbose with the test command it does not reflect why and where it is happening .

have you done the usual - delete the node_modules folder and re-install your dependencies? (i.e. yarn install if you're using yarn) - have you tried node version 22?

Yes i have done all of it , did a cache clean , deleted .lock , node_modules , rebuilt it still the same . @JaromandaX

so, you've even tried node version 22?

Yes @JaromandaX
